# Stop digest from processing certain element on demand

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to tell angualr to stop processing cetain element?
For exmaple I have a span text-input and a button.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someModel"/>
<span>{{ someModel }}</span>
<input type="button" ng-click="stopUpdatingSpan()" />
```

When i type in the text-box i want span to update accordingly.
But when I click the button i want the span to stop responding for updates from the text-box.

I know i can use compile + ng-non-bindable but im trying to figure out if there is a more elegant way.

Kind regards.